# Can I use modernizr to shim in support for http DELETE / PUT verbs?

Tags: modernizr

I'm trying to support a user base that is tied to IE8 currently and noticed that I can't use the 'DELETE' or 'PUT' verbs. Will using modernizr allow me to do this in IE8? If not what library if any will allow me to do this w/ out a hacky work-around like passing the verb in post data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [answers to this (old) SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers), you shouldn't have a problem with DELETE and PUT if you use them via the xmlHttpRequest object (ie Ajax calls).

In addition, [the Wikipedia page for xmlHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) also states that all the verbs are supported from IE7 upward.

They *aren't* supported from a straightforward form submission, but there's not really much need to use them in this context; POST should be sufficient. But for Ajax calls, you should be fine.

I recommend trying it in IE8 to confirm, but I don't think you'll have a problem.

Given that, I don't think you'll have a need for Modernizr to help you with this, unless you need IE6 support. But just to be sure, I had a look at [the Modernizr docs](http://modernizr.com/docs/), where it lists all the feature detections it does, and I couldn't see anything about http verbs. And even if Modernizr did detect it, you'd still need a polyfill to actually fix it, and I don't know of anything that would be able to do that. .... So it's a good thing you probably won't need it, then.

Comment: for anyone reading this @Spudley is correct -DELETE and PUT in IE8 + works as expected (seems I was having a different issue for some odd reason)